# Add the numeric part of names for list of dataframes as a column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, datatable

I have a list of data. In this list, it is either datatable or dataframe. After this problem, I'll bind the list.

**Data example:**

```
players
$`0001playeraway`
      key NO        MIN 2PTM 2PTA 2PT(%) 3PTM 3PTA 3PT(%) FGM FGA FG(%) FTM FTA FT(%) OR DR REB AST TO STL BS PF
   1:   * 17   40:00:00    9   15     60    0    0      0   9  15    60   2   4    50  1  8   9   2  4   1  2  1
   2:   * 16   40:00:00    4    8     50    8   13     62  12  21    57  20  22    91  2  3   5   4  4   0  0  3
   3:   * 10   33:02:00    2    4     50    0    3      0   2   7    29   0   0     0  0  4   4   1  3   1  0  4
   4:   *  3   27:46:00    2    3     67    0    0      0   2   3    67   6   6   100  1  4   5   0  1   4  0  3
   5:      1   26:24:00    1    1    100    0    2      0   1   3    33   1   2    50  1  0   1   1  0   1  0  4

$`0102playeraway`
      key NO        MIN 2PTM 2PTA 2PT(%) 3PTM 3PTA 3PT(%) FGM FGA FG(%) FTM FTA FT(%) OR DR REB AST TO STL BS PF
   1:   *  9   40:00:00    1    3     33    2    7     29   3  10    30   3   4    75  1  4   5   8  1   4  1  3
   2:   * 53   38:18:00    6   14     43    0    0      0   6  14    43   6   8    75  5  3   8   3  4   0  2  5
   3:   * 13   35:16:00    3    8     38    1    2     50   4  10    40   2   5    40  1  3   4   5  0   0  0  5
   4:   * 23   31:42:00    2    7     29    2    8     25   4  15    27   7   7   100  1  7   8   1  1   0  0  2
   5:     14      22:08    2    3     67    2    4     50   4   7    57   0   0     0  0  2   2   2  1   0  0  1
```

The rest is omitted.

How I can assign a value to the data table name in the list?

**Desired Output:**

```
players
$`0001playeraway`
      year key NO        MIN 2PTM 2PTA 2PT(%) 3PTM 3PTA 3PT(%) FGM FGA FG(%) FTM FTA FT(%) OR DR REB AST TO STL BS PF
   1: 0001  * 17   40:00:00    9   15     60    0    0      0   9  15    60   2   4    50  1  8   9   2  4   1  2  1
   2: 0001  * 16   40:00:00    4    8     50    8   13     62  12  21    57  20  22    91  2  3   5   4  4   0  0  3
   3: 0001  * 10   33:02:00    2    4     50    0    3      0   2   7    29   0   0     0  0  4   4   1  3   1  0  4
   4: 0001  *  3   27:46:00    2    3     67    0    0      0   2   3    67   6   6   100  1  4   5   0  1   4  0  3
   5: 0001     1   26:24:00    1    1    100    0    2      0   1   3    33   1   2    50  1  0   1   1  0   1  0  4

$`0102playeraway`
      year key NO        MIN 2PTM 2PTA 2PT(%) 3PTM 3PTA 3PT(%) FGM FGA FG(%) FTM FTA FT(%) OR DR REB AST TO STL BS PF
   1: 0102  *  9   40:00:00    1    3     33    2    7     29   3  10    30   3   4    75  1  4   5   8  1   4  1  3
   2: 0102  * 53   38:18:00    6   14     43    0    0      0   6  14    43   6   8    75  5  3   8   3  4   0  2  5
   3: 0102  * 13   35:16:00    3    8     38    1    2     50   4  10    40   2   5    40  1  3   4   5  0   0  0  5
   4: 0102  * 23   31:42:00    2    7     29    2    8     25   4  15    27   7   7   100  1  7   8   1  1   0  0  2
   5: 0102    14      22:08    2    3     67    2    4     50   4   7    57   0   0     0  0  2   2   2  1   0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a simple `Map` with `substr`; no need for additional packages.

`L` shall serve as an example of a mixed list of `data.frame`s and `data.table`s:

```
L
# $`0001playeraway`
# X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $`0102playeraway`
# X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $`1003playeraway`
# X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1:  1  4  7 10
# 2:  2  5  8 11
# 3:  3  6  9 12
```

*Method:*

```
library(data.table)
dat <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x) cbind(year=substr(names(L)[x], 1, 4), L[[x]]), seq(L)))
dat
#    year X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1: 0001  1  4  7 10
# 2: 0001  2  5  8 11
# 3: 0001  3  6  9 12
# 4: 0102  1  4  7 10
# 5: 0102  2  5  8 11
# 6: 0102  3  6  9 12
# 7: 1003  1  4  7 10
# 8: 1003  2  5  8 11
# 9: 1003  3  6  9 12
```

Since `data.table` dominates the process, do `dat <- as.data.frame(dat)` if you want a `data.frame` after.

***Data***

```
L <- list(`0001playeraway` = structure(list(X1 = 1:3, X2 = 4:6, X3 = 7:9, 
    X4 = 10:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), 
    `0102playeraway` = structure(list(X1 = 1:3, X2 = 4:6, X3 = 7:9, 
        X4 = 10:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L)), `1003playeraway` = structure(list(X1 = 1:3, X2 = 4:6, 
        X3 = 7:9, X4 = 10:12), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `purrr::imap` and `dplyr::mutate` to add a column to all of the dataframes in the list with the name of each of element. Here, I am also using `sringr::str_extract` to get the numeric part of the names as desired.

```r
#some data to work with as an example:
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y=letters[1:3])
listdfs <- list("tr088text" = df1,"character963" = df1,"00123string" = df1)

library(tidyverse)

imap(listdfs, ~mutate(year = str_extract(.y, "\\-*\\d+\\.*\\d*") , .x))

#> $tr088text
#>   x y year
#> 1 1 a  088
#> 2 2 b  088
#> 3 3 c  088
#> 
#> $character963
#>   x y year
#> 1 1 a  963
#> 2 2 b  963
#> 3 3 c  963
#> 
#> $`00123string`
#>   x y  year
#> 1 1 a 00123
#> 2 2 b 00123
#> 3 3 c 00123
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're planning to bind the dataframes anyway, you could skip a step or two by using `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` with the argument `.id = "year"` to include the list element names as new variable `year`. Using data:

```r
library(data.table)

players <- list(`0001playeraway` = data.table(NO = 1:5),
                `0102playeraway` = data.table(NO = 6:10)
                )
```

You can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(players, .id = "year")
```

Which returns:

```r
             year NO
1  0001playeraway  1
2  0001playeraway  2
3  0001playeraway  3
4  0001playeraway  4
5  0001playeraway  5
6  0102playeraway  6
7  0102playeraway  7
8  0102playeraway  8
9  0102playeraway  9
10 0102playeraway 10
```

If you really just want the numbers, you could use something like `df$year <- sub("(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$year)`, or just pipe the output from `bind_rows` into `mutate`, e.g.:

```r
bind_rows(players, .id = "year") %>%
    mutate(year = sub("(\\d+).*", "\\1", year))
```

Which returns:

```r
   year NO
1  0001  1
2  0001  2
3  0001  3
4  0001  4
5  0001  5
6  0102  6
7  0102  7
8  0102  8
9  0102  9
10 0102 10
```

*Note that this returns a `data.frame`. If you need a `data.table` just pipe the output from `mutate` into `as.data.table`.*